# GTK2: How to change a specific color in a GTK theme

Tags: gtk

I use FlatStudioDark GTK theme from here: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=154296

In that theme I have some problems to change one specific color (I think is one of the GtkTreeView element). Let me show you with pictures.

You see in the picture the file-browser "Thunar", I want to have the same color over all rows and columns (except the column-headers which should have that darkened color), for example the columns: "Name", "Size", "Type" all show the same colors, but the selected "Date Modified" on the right is more dark for the rows (or area). How do I change the darkened color in "Date Modified" to be the same as the other columns and rows (I'm not talking about the column-header themselves)?

[image: Thunar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding this line to my gtkrc:

```
GtkTreeView::row_ending_details = 1
```